# The WordPress main menu appear twice in my theme, why?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am going crazy with the following WordPress custom theme that use **BootStrap** CSS framework: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

As you can see I have a problem with the horizontal main menu in my header.

To create the WP dynamic main menu having the classic BootStra style I use the **wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php** class inserting it in my theme following its documentation that you can read it: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

So, according to the previous documentation, I have perform the following operations:

1) I have put the ** wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php** class inside the root of my custom theme

2) I have require it in my **functions.php** file, putting in it the following code:

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
```

3) In my **header.php** file I have insert the following code:

```
<body>
    <!-- Header e barra di navigazione -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">

                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'menu' => 'primary', 
                        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                        'depth' => 2,
                        'container' => 'div', 
                        /*'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default',*/
                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 
                        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback', 
                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>

            </div>
    </nav>
    </header><!-- /header -->
```

4) And finnally I have register the nav menu in my theme putting this code into my **functions.php** file:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'THEMENAME'),
) );
```

Ok, as you can see I can see the main menu but I see it twice: one is the correct visualization (the one with red background) but appear a second main menu upper and I can't understand why (I never declared it twice)

Do you have some idea about this issue? How can I try to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Check your Wordpress menu settings. Choose a primary menu from there and remove the menu you don't use.

Comment: I have only a single menu in my WP menu settings !!!

Comment: Why is the container_class commented out in the wp_nav_walker?

Comment: Please be sure to mark an answer as correct if you find the solution to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

In your code source I can see 2 menus called in your page. The menu you want to get rid of is one of the first things called in your page. It belongs to this div:

If you don't want the padding/margin, the easy way is to add to your CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
display: none;
}
```

But look at your page source, you have all this code before your `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-12 active"><a title="Home" href="http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a title="Sample Page" href="http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a title="Google" href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

This is what you need to remove. This code is way above what you copied in your post, it may also be in your header.php file depending on how your theme is organized. It's the very first thing called in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your wp_nav_menu function call is NOT listed in both your "functions.php" doc and also in your header.php file.

I was getting the same issue until I removed the wp_nav_menu function from "functions.php" and included it (along with the arguments) only in my header.php file. I still do the following in my functions.php file:

add_theme_support('menus');
register_nav_menu('primary','Primary Menu');

but now in my header.php file, I put the rest:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
  'theme_location'  => 'primary',
  'menu'            => 'primary',
  'container'       => "nav",
  'container_class' => false,
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => 'navigation',
  'menu_id'         => '',
  'echo'            => true,
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```